# If every bounded subsequence converges, then the sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis

I came across the following statement in a true or false exercise:

**If every bounded subsequence converges, then the sequence converges**

The answer is false, but I am struggling to figure out a counterexample to the statement to show that it is false.

Comment: A sequence with no bounded subsequences (e.g., $1,2,3,4,\ldots$) would satisfy this statement vacuously. You could interweave this with a convergent sequence to get a nonvacuous counterexample, e.g. $1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,\ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

[Converting my commment to an answer.]

A sequence with no bounded subsequences (e.g., $1,2,3,4,\ldots$) would satisfy this statement vacuously.

You could interweave this with a convergent sequence to get a non-vacuous counterexample, e.g. $1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,\ldots$.